# how to add a .net 4.0 dll to a project running on dotnet 3.5

Tags: .net, frameworks, version

I have a class library build in .net framework 4.0. i want to add it to an old project build in .net framework 3.5 .. is there any way to do it other than upgrading the old project? also it will be helpful if you could tell me how to downgrade my dll to 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to run the .NET 4.0 DLL in a .NET 3.5 process.

If you have the source code, then you can convert it to .NET 3.5 by changing the target framework of the project (either in Visual Studio or by hand). If the source code is relying on .NET 4.0 specific features then you will have to change it to work with .NET 3.5. Whether or not this is feasible depends on how heavily the code is relying on .NET 4.0 features and whether the same effect can be achieved using only .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the source to both the 4.0 DLL and the 3.5 project? If so, your can:

1. Port & rebuild the 4.0 DLL to 3.5
2. Port & rebuild your 3.5 project to .NET 4.0.
3. Coerce your 3.5 project to run on the 4.0 CLR by modifying your app's config:

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <startup >
>     <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
>     <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
>   </startup>
> </configuration>
> ```

If you choose option 3, be sure to test your code thoroughly as your code may reference API's that have changed behavior and/or API's and may result in runtime breakage that's hard to detect and fix.

Be sure to **[read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx)** covering the ability of .NET 4.0 apps to better handle components built for earlier versions of .NET.

It's perhaps wise to start preparing now for the future and re-factoring your code to push all your core business logic into [.NET Portable Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) which will make it easier to reuse that code in Windows Desktop, Windows Metro-style apps, Windows Phone apps, Silverlight apps, XBox apps, etc.

HTH.

Comment: my problem was that i cant port the project from 3.5 to 4.0. it is been developed by my other teammates also. i had created this class library for a windows form project and now i am creating the web version of it which has to be integrated in the old project as a new module.

Comment: Then your best bet is to create a port of your library that is compiled to target the same platform as the rest of your team.

Comment: @RichardTurner Having same problem and option 3 seems to be the only reasonable answer to my problem.  However I get an error saying "Could not find schema information for the element 'supportedRuntime' when I try this.  Should you have any additional info about that I would love to hear it.  Thanks!